# How to split a line of txt file into 3 values per line

Tags: python

I have a file which has a line of values separated by spaces

```
0 380 -222 0 382 -218 45 428 174 . . .
```

and so on.

what is the fastest way to split each 3 values in a new line ?

like this way

```
0 380 -222
0 382 -218
45 428 174
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initially need to split the string you have based on the spaces. Then you can choose many ways to combine elements of that list and print them.

To split the string to a list you generally use `split()`.

```
# test string
s = "0 380 -222 0 382 -218 45 428 174"
# splitting based on the spaces
l = s.split()
```

One of the options to combine them is to use `zip` taking note of the *slices* you take in order to define the elements you want. This will create *tuples* which will contain your elements.

You can then *unpack* these tuples in a `for` loop and print or do anything else you want with them:

```
for a,b,c in zip(l[0::3], l[1::3], l[2::3]): 
    print a, b, c
```

Which in turn prints:

```
0 380 -222
0 382 -218
45 428 174
```

---

After @boardrider's comment, I'll note that in case the list length is not divisible by `3` you can use [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (`zip_longest` in `Py3`) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) (and supply an optionary filler value if you need it) in order to get all possible values in the string `s`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

s = "0 380 -222 0 382 -218 45 428 293 9298 8192 919 919"
l = s.split()

for a,b,c in zip_longest(l[0::3], l[1::3], l[2::3]): 
    print a, b, c
```

Which now yields:

```
0 380 -222
0 382 -218
45 428 293
9298 8192 919
919 None None
```

Comment: Nice solution. I think that's about the most elegant, most pythonic way to do it.

Comment: Note that this solution won't display all numbers if `len(l) % 3 != 0`

Comment: Noted, and added, thanks for pointing that out so I can fill it in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xrange` too-

```
l='0 380 -222 0 382 -218 45 428 174'.split(' ')
result = [l[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(l), 3)]
for three in result:
    print ' '.join(three)
```

Prints-

```
0 380 -222
0 382 -218
45 428 174
```

Comment: Also `for i in xrange(0, len(l), 3): print ' '.join(l[i:i+3])`. There is no need variable `result` here.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a generalized grouping function:

```
def grouper(n, iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,...s3n-1), ..."
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

line = "0 380 -222 0 382 -218 45 428 174"

for group in grouper(3, line.split()):
    print(' '.join(group))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it:

```
num_columns = 3
with open(file_name) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        for count, number in enumerate(line.strip().split(), 1):
            print '{:4}'.format(number),
            if count % num_columns == 0:
                print
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will read an input file called `input.txt` containing your space delimited entries, and create you an output file called `output.txt` with the entries split 3 per line:

```
from itertools import izip, islice

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    values = []
    for line in f_input:
        values.extend(line.split())

    ivalues = iter(values)

    for triple in iter(lambda: list(islice(ivalues, 3)), []):
        f_output.write(' '.join(triple) + '\n')
```

Giving you an output file as follows:

```
0 380 -222
0 382 -218
45 428 174
```

Tested using Python 2.7.9